# string.split - by multiple character delimiter },{

Tags: asp.net

i am having trouble splitting a string in c# with a delimiter of `"},{"`.

For example the string `"abc},{rfd},{5},{,},{."`

Should yield an array containing:

```
abc
rfd
5
,
.
```

But I cannot seem to get it to work, even if I try RegEx I cannot get a split on the delimiter.

EDIT: Essentially I wanted to resolve this issue without the need for a Regular Expression. The solution that I accept is;

```
string Delimiter = "},{";  
var Result[] = StringToSplit.Split(new[] { Delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I am glad to be able to resolve this split question.

Comment: @dotnetmirror.com the OP has a `,` as part of the array elements in the string.

Comment: Can not do this as the string could be like "a,bc},{rf,d},{5},{,},{.," too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var sample = "abc},{rfd},{5},{,},{.";
var result = Regex.Split(sample, Regex.Escape("},{"));
foreach (var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string array in split function

```
string strMultiChars = "abc},{rfd},{5},{,},{.";
//split by string array
 string[] splitByMultipleSring = strMultiChars.Split(new string[] { "},{" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
 foreach (string s in splitByMultipleSring)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
  }
```